# Difference of two dates using c# as an integer value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to calculate the number of days between 2 dates as an integer value and so far I have tried the following:

```
int Days = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now));

int Days = Convert.ToInt32((CurrentDate - DateTime.Now).Days);
```

However, neither statement is giving me the correct output. The first one is giving me the error  *Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'*. The second one is giving `Days` as 0.

Comment: What value are you using for `CurrentDate`? Is it possible that zero is the correct answer?

Comment: @Learner: Run it with debugging and double check the value for `CurrentDate`. Also consider that perhaps your `TimeSpan` difference is less than 24 hours. So you might have September 17th at 1pm and September 18th at 10am. In this case, I'm pretty sure `Days` would report `0`. EDIT: In which case, try comparing `CurrentDay.Date` and `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

[`TimeSpan.Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) is already an `int` value so you don't need to cast it:

```
int Days = (CurrentDate - DateTime.Now).Days;
```

So i assume that 0 days is correct. What is `CurrentDate`?

If you want to round the `TimeSpan` according to the hour part you could use this method:

```
public static int DaysRounded(TimeSpan input, MidpointRounding rounding = MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
{
    int roundupHour = rounding == MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero ? 12 : 13;
    if (input.Hours >= roundupHour)
        return input.Days + 1;
    else
        return input.Days;
}

int days = DaysRounded(TimeSpan.FromHours(12)); // 1
```

Comment: I'm assuming Learner wants to use `TotalDays`, not the `Days` _component_ of the time span. EDIT: On second read, I suppose it could be ambiguous from the question.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: What's the difference apart from the fact that `Days` is already an `int`?

Comment: If the timespan is 1 year 2 days, then `.Days` will be `2`, not `367`; `TotalDays` will return a different result.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm totally wrong on this. I _thought_ `Days` only reported the value after years, but it doesn't. It simply pre-truncates the same values as `TotalDays`. Disregard me, I feel like an ass. :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: current date can be any date as i am selecting that date from the calendar control, it can be today, tommorrow or any.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: This "truncate"-rule applies only for the `Hours`,`Minutes`,`Seconds` etc. properties.

Comment: @Learner: Try eliminating the time component of your `DateTime` by using `CurrentDate.Date` and `DateTime.Now.Date` and see if that helps. Do you care about hours difference or purely "The user said June 20th and today is June 19th"?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yeah, I'm just discovering that now. I haven't had to work with `TimeSpan` _except_ in the context of hours/minutes/seconds. I feel like a bum.

Comment: @DanPuzey: That's true for the other properties like `Hours` but not for `Days` since that's the largest property, there is no `Month` or `Years`.

Comment: Thanks all, I removed Time component from DateTime and it worked for me, thanks Chris Sinclair. And I appreciate the answer of @TimSchmelter: it is the right way when you really want to count the time part of the Datetime.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: my apologies, that's good point I'd completely overlooked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this.

```
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt2 = CurrentDtae;

        int result = (int)((dt2 - dt1).TotalDays);
```